# SQL conditional AND clause?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, conditional-statements

In my query I want to add the and clause in query if a specific condition occur.
See the where clause of my query

```
1     and ps.dept=dept.deptid  

2     and ps.sdept=deptsub.deptid 

3     and

4   if(ps.dept<>ps.sdept) 

5    begin

6    deptsub.Parent=dept.deptid 

7  end

8  and ps.deptcategory=deptcat.category
```

At 4 I want if condition fulfil then 6 should be added in query else not how is this possible.thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
and ps.dept=dept.deptid  
and ps.sdept=deptsub.deptid 
and ( ps.dept=ps.sdept or deptsub.Parent=dept.deptid )
and ps.deptcategory=deptcat.category
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing lines 4, 5, 6, and 7 with this:

```
deptsub.Parent = 
case when ps.dept <> ps.sdept then dept.deptid 
else deptsub.Parent 
end
```

The case statement will substitute dept.deptid when your condition is met, otherwise it will just substitute deptsub.parent - which will always = deptsub.parent

Answer (score 3):

```
and ps.dept=dept.deptid  
and ps.sdept=deptsub.deptid 
and
(
    ((ps.dept<>ps.sdept) and (deptsub.Parent=dept.deptid))
    or
    (ps.dept = ps.sdept)
)
and ps.deptcategory=deptcat.category
```